# how to generate token in quickbook dynamically

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, invoice

I am able to generate a token using web view by using node SDK has given [here](https://github.com/intuitdeveloper/oauth2-nodejs) 
but I in that process I need to manually generate token than I can use it can anyone know how to implement it in nodejs in the right way so that I don't need to generate it manually for the API
https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/4620816365010494740/invoice?minorversion=40.

Comment: Specifically what token or value are you talking about here?

Comment: I am asking for token marked in the image

https://ibb.co/BTb6dR1

Comment: This is all documented in detail here (it even includes Node.js examples): https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#obtain-the-access-token